# Protractor in vscode - how to display the element content in the debug?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, protractor

I am running protractor/typescript in vscode.
I open "JavascriptDebugTerminal and run with "npm start".
The deubug seems ok but all element variables seems similar in the debug window.
I need an optino to review the exact element content. How can I do it?
(getting the elements by element.by(css('className'))